# Custom html5 validation regex for phone numbers

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I have a from in which user has to enter his phone number.

```html
<input id="username" title="Please enter valid phone number " maxlength="10"  pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="phone"  size="20"
              
            required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid phone number.')"    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" >
```

It works fine when validating but only for Numbers. 
I want the numbers to be specifically starting from 971 as it is limited to UAE numbers only. How can I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding that number at first and reduce the  occurrence number

```
pattern="971[0-9]{7}"
```

```html
<input id="username" title="Please enter valid phone number " maxlength="10"  pattern="971[0-9]{7}" name="phone"  size="20"
              
            required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid phone number.')"    onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" >
```

Comment: Got it ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it starting specifically from `971`, then this will work(assuming 10 digits of number)

```
971[0-9]{7}
```

Comment: The above answer worked and yours is also correct .. Thank you :)